# Homotopy invariance of winding number in complex analysis.

Tags: complex-analysis

In topology, the winding number is homotopy invariant under the definition $n(\gamma,a)=\frac{\tilde{\theta}(\beta)-\tilde{\theta}(\alpha)}{2\pi}.$

I assume the must be true in the framework of complex analysis. Suppose you take as definition for the winding number $n(C,a)$ of a curve $C$ through $a$ to be 
$$
n(C,a)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_C\frac{dz}{z-a}.
$$

Is is still true that $n(C,a)$ is hopotopy invariant under smooth curves $C$ not going through $a$? Thank you.

Comment: It seems intuitively that it would be the case that $n(C,a)$ is homotopy invariant under $C$, but I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both definitions agree, so the winding number is homotopy invariant. See Stewart and Tall, "Complex Analysis", section 7.5. You might be also interested in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4054/intuitive-explanation-of-cauchys-integral-formula-in-complex-analysis/4061#4061) and, perhaps, my answer therein.

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to show it without referring back to the topological definition?

Comment: Indeed: look at op.cit., theorems 9.3 and 9.4.