# Physical interpretation of Cauchy's integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis

what is the Physical interpretation of Cauchy's integral formula ?

Comment: Repeat of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4054/intuitive-explanation-of-cauchys-integral-formula-in-complex-analysis  ???

Comment: @Euler: I think this is more specific. None of the answers in that thread give physical interpretations.

Comment: @Naveen: start here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations#Physical_interpretation

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest Chapter 9 of Cohen's book [Conformal Mapping on Riemann Surfaces](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Conformal-Mapping-Riemann-Surfaces-Harvey/dp/0486640256/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1346265469&sr=8-1-fkmr0), where he relates existence theorems of [Harmonic Differentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_differential) and the Cauchy-Riemann Equations to the study of [Electrostatics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrostatics) and [Hydrodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrodynamics).