# What exactly is Complex Residue?

Tags: residue-calculus

I know how to calculate residues of several functions, but I really don't know what residue is. Is there any way to really explain what residue is?

Comment: For one, it's the coefficient from a Laurent series expansion

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/a/255874/589.

Comment: Could it be the solution to division by zero? After all, it is finding something at the pole(s) of a function.

Comment: AstroFox - the integral is around the pole, not through it.

Comment: @AstroFox: In a word, "no". First, division by zero has no meaning in the context of arithmetic. Second, the residue of a simple pole can be an arbitrary complex number, while "the solution to division by zero" would have a single value (if it were to have any arithmetic utility). Third, the functions $f(z) = 1/z^{n}$ ($n \geq 2$ an integer) "involve division by zero" at $z = 0$, but each has residue equal to zero.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. It is quite interesting to study the whole phenomena with singularities and discontinuities of functions. Thanks for the quick answers!